# RequireJS sometimes not loading modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a really strange issue that suddenly started happening, its probably some race condition or something--but it always worked perfectly fine...
And for some reason, all requirejs loaded modules are quircky.

Its probably something silly but im killing myself over this, especially since nothing has changed in months..

Not using data-main, legacy project.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var require = {
        baseUrl: '/path/to/js/files',
    };
</script>
<script src="require.js"></script>
```

**Inline script tab**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs(['com/some/file']);
</script>
```

**JS file**

```
define(function() {
    console.log("this loads 50/50...");
});
```

Comment: As currently written, there's nothing in your question that suggests you should be having loading problems. The classic mistake is to have a `data-main` that loads the configuration and an inline script just after that does a `require` call, but you do not use `data-main`. Right now your question reads as a summary of the real code. I suggest you create a [mcve], or something as close as possible to it and put that in the question. (Also, you should explain exactly how you detect that your module is not loading.)

Answer (score -1):

After some divide and conquer it became clear the google webfont loader was the culprit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Quicksand:400,700:latin' ] }
    };
    (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
    })();
</script>
```